# github actions: how to check if current push has new tag (is new release)?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

```
name: test-publish

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    strategy:
      ...
    steps:
      ...

  publish:
    needs: test
    if: github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref???
    steps:
      ...  # eg: publish package to PyPI
```

What should I put in `jobs.publish.if` in order to check that this commit is new release?

Is this okay: `contains(github.ref, '/tags/')`?

What will happen if I push code and tag at the same time?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could do this to check if the current push event is for a tag starting with `v`.

```
  publish:
    needs: test
    if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v')
```

As you pointed out though, I don't think you can guarantee that this is a new release. My suggestion would be to use `on: release` instead of `on: push`. This will only trigger on a newly tagged release.

See the docs for `on: release` here:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

Comment: I use that workflow for testing every push and I don't want to make separate workflow with exactly the same testing job and additional publishing job. So `on: release` won't do. Also after inspecting `github` object I concluded that parsing `ref` with `startsWith/contains` is a valid solution here, because there was no other info about release.

Comment: Could you have the action triggered with both push and release and then make the publishing step conditional on that like `if: github.event_name == 'release'`?

Comment: Please update link to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

Comment: This method doesn't work for me. `github.ref` contains `refs/heads/blabla` instead of tags.

I tried few combinations:

Commit push, and then create and push tag (with `--tags` options).
Commit, tag and then push (with `--tags` options too of course).
[link to by CI job](https://github.com/kaomoneus/cppl/runs/2978231466?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: I'm really confused, @StepanDyatkovskiy if this doesn't work, why did it receive so many upvotes?

Comment: @StepanDyatkovskiy Looks like you need `on: push: tags: ...` or `on: release` for the `github.ref` to be set to the tag. See the docs for how `github.ref` is set depending on trigger: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release

Comment: @erb Spot on. I realized my workflow would only run on commit push but not tag push. Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

An alternative way to use a GitHub Release as a trigger (in case if you want to use tags freely and release specific versions only):

```
on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  release-job:
    name: Releasing
    if: github.event_name == 'release' && github.event.action == 'created'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `github.ref_type` to check the type of ref that triggered the workflow run.

> The type of ref that triggered the workflow run. Valid values are `branch` or `tag`.

```yaml
  publish:
    needs: test
    if: github.ref_type == 'tag'
```